# TextField pairing in Django

Tags: python, django, web-applications, textfield

(I am writing one of my first Django apps so the question is kinda noobish, sorry).

I am creating something like a lecture summarizing tool for students and I need to make TextField pairs - Lecture_title (1) and Lecture_summary (2). The problem is that Lecture_title  and Lecture_summary will probably need to be separate models, because they will have their own fields (name, pub_date) + I want to let users display only a list of Lecture_titles or search over lecture_summaries. The users will be able to add / remove those Lecture_titles and Lecture_summaries in my web app dynamically. Each Lecture_title will be unique to and will have its' lecture_summary.

**The question is** - what would be the best way to create TextFied pairs in Django? I at least hope to receive some links to some reading material regarding the idea..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of your models, you may be better of by going for a single model solution like pointed out by niekas.

But if you want to split the data into several models, you can have a look at this solution.

I'm not very skilled yet in Django, but one way to achieve this is to create a model `Lecture` which has two one-to-one fields `LectureTitle` and `LectureSummary`. By using a base class, you can add some fields that you want all your models to have. This is usefull if you for example want a last modified `DateTimeField` for all your models.

```
from django.db import models


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Lecture(BaseModel):
    title = models.OneToOneField(LectureTitle)
    summary = models.OneToOneField(LectureSummary)


class LectureTitle(BaseModel):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=30)


class LectureSummary(BaseModel):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
```

This might be a bit more flexible than the solution given by niekas.

To access the lecture from `LectureSummary` or `LectureTitle`, just use `lecture`. This field is created automatically on the other side of the one-to-one field.

**To print all titles:**

```
for lecture in Lecture.objects.all():
    print lecture.title.name
```

**Search for content in summaries:**

```
# search_str is the search string from user
for lecture in Lecture.objects.filter(summary.content__contains(search_str):
    print lecture.title.name
```

**Update based on your comment:**
That should be pretty easy:

```
for lecture in Lecture.objects.all():
    #lecture.title.name gives you the title of your lecture
    #lecture.summary.content gives you the content of the lecture
```

Comment: Thank you. You answer seems a little bit closer to what I am trying to achieve. I have missed one important part though: my idea is to display the main page like this:

Lecture title <another line> Lecture summary <another line> Another lecture title <another line> Another lecture summary … etc. Do you have any idea how should I retrieve objects from my models like that ? Users will be able to "CRUD" the data dynamically.

Comment: @Eimantas See my updated answer. You should ask a separate question if you need help with the view and the template for your app, since that would be outside the scope of this question. (post a link to the new Q here if you do so, and I'll have a look at it)

Comment: As a general comment: If you need do dynamically change the view of your app, you may want to use javascript.